# Default datetime data in Silex/Symfony2 forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, silex

I'm trying to create a form that will allow users to edit data. I need to read a value from the a table and pre-populate the form with that data.

In the code below I'm trying to set a value of `2007-02-20 16:48:00` in the form.

What I tried:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder( 'form' )
    ->add('start', 'datetime', array(
      'data' => '2007-02-20 16:48:00')
  )
    ->add('end', 'datetime')
    ->getForm();
```

What I got:

> UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument of type "\DateTime",
>   "string" given

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony wants a DateTime object, so try:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder( 'form' )
    ->add('start', 'datetime', array(
        'data' => new \DateTime('2007-02-20 16:48:00'))
      )
    ->add('end', 'datetime')
    ->getForm();
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can set the fields "input" parameter to "string". (Just adding this for the sake of completeness.)